# More elegant way to separate a list of dict(s) based on a value from an identical key in each dict in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dynamic, attributes

I get a return of a list of dict(s), from a program, that have the same key in each dict, I would like to set a class attribute list based on the :value in each. The dict list can have multiple same values

```
[
    {"key":"value"}, 
    {"key":"differentvalue"}, 
    {"key":"value"}, 
    {"key":"newValue"}, 
    {"key":"newValue"}
]
```

now i have a class like this `

```
class DynamicAttributesFromDict:
    def __init__(self, listed):
        for i in range(len(listed)):
            name = listed[i]["key"]
            p = getattr(self, name, [])
            p.append(listed[i])
            setattr(self, name, p)
```

I have it this way so i can access certain lists of dicts by obj.newValue or obj.value etc.
This is just an example the real dicts in the list are much more longer and created from a program.

Should I use hasattr first to check for the attribute and the getattr to append?

The above works, but it seems sketchy

Kind of new to python classes, so any help would be appreciated

Edit:

a better representation I think

```
from pprint import pprint
listdict = [
    {"key":"value", "difkey":"something"}, 
    {"key":"differentvalue", "xkey":"yvalue"}, 
    {"key":"value"}, 
    {"key":"newValue"}, 
    {"key":"newValue"}
]

class DynamicAttributesFromDict:
    def __init__(self, listed):
        for i in range(len(listed)):
            name = listed[i]["key"]
            p = getattr(self, name, [])
            p.append(listed[i])
            setattr(self, name, p)

f = DynamicAttributesFromDict(listdict)
pp(f.value)
pp(f.differentvalue)
pp(f.newValue)
```

Comment: A simple way to improve your code is to iterate over `listed` directly, rather than iterating over its indexes.

Comment: Are these actually identical values too or is the data representative?

Comment: @COLDSPEED representative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter(lambda x: x['key'] == 'value', my_data)
```

Outputs a generator object that turns into a list like this:

```
[{'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}]
```

Or we could do a list comprehension:

```
[d for d in my_data if d['key'] == 'value']
```

I'm rereading your question to make sure I answered it properly, and I'm not sure I did. Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Apologies for my bluntness, but how does this answer relate to the question? If understood the question correctly, the OP is trying to find a cleaner way to initialize class attributes from dictionary values.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I added a line to the end of my answer about that, actually.

Comment: The title of the question makes it sound like this is what is wanted, but the description leaves me wondering if I'm just clueless.

Comment: I agree. The title and body of the question do not seem to be in agreeance. In cases such as this is is probably best to just vote(or flag) to close the the question and ask the OP to add clarification.

Comment: Of course, but I made the answer before I realized that I may have misunderstood the question. I'm still not sure I did, though.